# Open mailto after click in IE8/Chrome

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer-8, window, mailto

I'm currently trying to do the following:

Trigger: click on a name in a select list.

Action : open mailto-link in current window, thus opening an email client.

```
$(document).ready(function(){    

// Define click-event
$('option').click(function(){
    var mail = $(this).attr('value');
    window.open('mailto:'+mail, '_self');
    });

});
```

I've also tried using this instead of window.open:

`parent.location.href= 'mailto:'+mail;`

However, both work only in firefox, get no errors/results in IE8 or Chrome.

Anybody know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (works for me on IE8)

```
$('option').change(function() {
   var target = 'mailto:' + $('option:selected', this).text();
   window.location=target;
});
```

There's probably a better way to do this but I use a similar thing on one of my pages.

If the email address can be stored as the select option value, use .val() instead of .text() at the end.

Comment: That almost works, have to change the option-selector to "select", thanks a bunch :)

Comment: Doh! Yes, it should be the name of the select, not the option. Apologies :)

Comment: Also, if you tag your question with the tag jQuery, you may get some more attention for it...